# Gaussian process with constant variance after mean centering

Tags: python, gaussian

I'm new to working with Gaussian processes, so please target answers to a relative beginner. I'm trying to sample correlated noise where the mean of each sample is 0 (i.e., mean-centered), so I've been running the following code. However, while the variance across samples is the same for each dimension before mean-centering each sample, mean-centering causes the variance to be increasingly large at the ends of the vectors. I'm fairly certain I understand why this happens, but I'm struggling to figure out if there's a way to have each sample mean-centered while maintaining equal variance across dimensions.

```
import numpy as np

def rbf_kernel(x_1, x_2, sig):
    return np.exp((-(x_1-x_2)**2)/2*(sig**2))

X = np.array([[0.08333333],
              [0.25      ],
              [0.41666667],
              [0.58333333],
              [0.75      ],
              [0.91666667]])

r = 0.1

covNoise = np.zeros((6, 6))
for i, x1 in enumerate(X):
    for j, x2 in enumerate(X):
        covNoise[i,j] = rbf_kernel(x1, x2, r)

noise = np.random.multivariate_normal(np.zeros(6), covNoise, 1000)

np.var(noise, axis=0)
# Variance before mean-centering -- variance is constant across the vector
# array([0.99994815, 0.99941361, 0.9989251 , 0.99848157, 0.99806782, 0.99768438])

noise_meanCentered = noise - noise.mean(axis=1, keepdims=True)
np.var(noise_meanCentered, axis=0)
# Variance after mean-centering -- variance is greatest at the ends of the vector
# array([0.15211363, 0.0589172, 0.01052137, 0.01053556, 0.0589244, 0.15203642])
```